# сосчитать сколько ошибок в веденном тексте

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я делаю тест где показывает правильно ли человек ответил на вопрос если введенное значение равно ответу в data-answr="ответ". Сейчас у меня просто показывает правильно ли человек ввел значение. Как сделать так что бы показывало сколько ошибок в предложении он допустил?

```js
  jQuery('.questions').find('textarea').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.toLowerCase() === jQuery(this).data('answer').toLowerCase()) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('good');
      jQuery(this).removeClass('error');
    } else {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('good');
      jQuery(this).addClass('error');
    }

    var goodAnswers = jQuery('.good').length;
    var badAnswers = jQuery('.error').length;


    jQuery('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">Допущено ошибок: '+ badAnswers +'</div>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Перепишите правильно:</p>

<p>Во дваре растет дериво</p>

<div class="message"></div>


<div class="questions">
<textarea class="form-control" data-answer="Во дворе растет дерево" rows="5" ></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам нужны регулярные выражения http://javascript.ru/regexp В двух словах их не объяснить, это отдельная тема для изучения. https://learn.javascript.ru/regular-expressions-javascript, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать несколькими способами

1) разбить предложения на слова и если слова в водимом тексте и "правильном" не совпадают то делать +1

2) считать расстояние Левенштейна для каждой пары слов

Я остановлюсь на втором пункте.

Расстояние Левенштейна между двумя строками в теории информации и компьютерной лингвистике — это минимальное количество операций вставки одного символа, удаления одного символа и замены одного символа на другой, необходимых для превращения одной строки в другую.
Подробней можно прочитать на [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0).

для ваших двух строк расстояние равно 2.

подсчет расстояния:

```
var inputStr = "Во дваре растет дериво";
var answerStr = "Во дворе растет дерево";

function levenshtein(a, b){
  if(a.length == 0) return b.length; 
  if(b.length == 0) return a.length; 

  var matrix = [];

  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = [i];
  }

  var j;
  for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
      if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1];
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i-1][j-1] + 1,
                                Math.min(matrix[i][j-1] + 1,
                                         matrix[i-1][j] + 1));
      }
    }
  }

  return matrix[b.length][a.length];
}
```